# How to add more folders on an existing folder?

Tags: python

I would like to add more folder on a existing folder.

I have a folder called 'folder_One'. In this folder there are already 10 subfolders, which are numbered with `0, 1, 2..., 9`. Now I want to create 10 more folders.

The name of the folder must also start after the last number of the already existing folder, i.e. If there is already folders which have the number `0, 1, 2, ..., 9`, then it should start from `10, 11, 12, ..., 19`.

If there are no subfolders in the folder `folder_One`, 10 new folders are to be created. How can I do that?

```
path_data = 'Data'
word = 'folder_One'
folder_length = 10

def create_folder():
    count = 0
    for startNum in range(folder_length):
        while os.path.exists(os.path.join(dir_path, word, str(startNum)):
            count += 1
            for folder in range(folder_length):
                 os.makedirs(os.path.join(dir_path, word, str(folder + count)))

        else:
            for folder in range(folder_length):\
                 os.makedirs(os.path.join(dir_path, word, str(folder)))
```

Comment: You need to figure out what the starting number should be. What ideas do you have for doing that?

Comment: With my current method, I already create 10 folders starting with 0 and ending with 9. Now I want to create more folders. As a start, this must be done after the last number of the folder. So here the case is that after 9 the number 10, 11, 12,... should be created als folder. Ive tried something but im getting a FileExistsError: [WinError 183].

Comment: You shouldn't change the code in your question 40+ minutes after asking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following code:

```py
path_data = 'Data'
word = 'folder_One'
folder_length = 10

def create_folder():
    base_path = os.path.join(path_data, word)
    init_folder = 0
    if os.path.exists(base_path):
        init_folder = max(map(lambda x: int(x), os.listdir(base_path))) + 1
    for folder in range(init_folder, init_folder + folder_length):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(base_path, str(folder)))
```